# Live Video Broadcasting in Android using Wowza Server for Live ip address

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-broadcast, wowza, broadcasting

I want to integrate **Video Broadcasting and Streaming** in my android application through **Wowza server**. I have tried many different thing like [this demo from JavaCV](https://github.com/vanevery/JavaCV_0.3_stream_test) and [this one from AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/).

But the only problem with [first one](https://github.com/vanevery/JavaCV_0.3_stream_test) is that it uses flv file format to broadcast on Wowza server. It uses FFmpegFrameRecorder to broadcast live video to wowza server (not VOD). To set format of the video broadcasted at server, it uses following method:

```
recorder.setFormat("flv");
```

So the main problem with this method is that when I use other formats, it doesn't work. For E.g.:

```
recorder.setFormat("mpeg"); //or something like mov, etc
```

The [second one](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/) was appropriate and had exactly what I needed. But I am facing a weird scenario in that one. It works perfectly fine (can broadcast Video with Audio) for localhost links like `rtsp://192.168.1.58:1935/live/myStream` but it fails to Broadcast live links like `rtsp://54.208.***.***:1935/live/myStream`. It shows as playing in wowza server but I cannot see Video or hear Audio from that link.

Please suggest a way to overcome this problem so that I can get Video and Audio at my end while boradcasting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [this code](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/) to communicate between Wowza and Android for Video Broadcasting part. I completed the part with completed success. The link given shows quite a good explanation on the topic and the configuration of Wowza server that needs to be done in order to make the brodcasting from Android happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try android-ffmpeg library. This will definitely help you!

Comment: Can you share me the link ?

Comment: http://rxwen.blogspot.in/2010/05/use-ffmpeg-to-setup-streaming-server-on.html Follow this link...

Comment: And can I broadcast video with .mp4 format to Wowza with that library ?

Comment: @Ricky- How do I integrate this in Native android code. As I am unable to understand this structure. can you provide me with a code snippet or something like that ??